# Uploading large bitmaps using WorkManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I'm trying to use WorkManager to upload a bitmap to the server. Basically the user takes a picture and presses a button to upload it to the server.

However, the problem comes when I try to serialise the bitmap using the Data.Builder class of Work Manager, which has a limit of 10240 bytes. Therefore, if I do the following:

```
val data = Data.Builder()
//Add parameter in Data class. just like bundle. You can also add Boolean and Number in parameter.
data.putString(IMAGE_NAME, identifier)
data.putByteArray(BITMAP_ARRAY, imageBytes)
```

The following crash will be thrown `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data cannot occupy more than 10240 bytes when serialized`

I could always save the photo to a file before starting the work manager, and in work manager read the file. However, I would rathe avoid all file management if possible, because the user could always close the app, etc.

I just wanted to save the file, if the server responded successful.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Is there a google "suggestion" for this kind of things?

Here is my `doWork()` of WorkManager functionality

```java
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val identifier = inputData.getString(IMAGE_NAME)!!
        val imageBytes = inputData.getByteArray(BITMAP_ARRAY)!!

        val result = executeRequest(identifier, imageBytes)

        return if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //saving image
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
            saveToInternalStorage(context, identifier, bitmap)
            Result.success()
        } else {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would rathe avoid all file management if possible, because the user could always close the app, etc.

Then you should not use WorkManager. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) states this clearly:

> WorkManager is not intended for in-process background work that can safely be terminated if the app process goes away

With regards to putting a lot of data in a `Data`, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#input_output) is clear on this as well:

> There is a maximum size limit of 10KB for Data objects. [...] If you need to pass more data in and out of your Worker, you should put your data elsewhere

So if you want to use WorkManager for this after all (which sounds like a good idea to me), you have to put the large bitmap in a file, put the URI of that file in the `Data` object, and then in your `doWork()` upload the bitmap from that file and then delete the file.

If you kill your app in in the middle of `doWork()`, the `WorkManager` framework will start your app process (without a UI) later (with increasing backoff time) and attempt to do the upload again.

Comment: It makes sense to save it in a file to send it later if the app could not or was closed. But the file management has always to exist in this case because of the force closed for example, right?
I mean, I will have to check in every app start, if the temporary file is already there and the work is not schedule, right?

Comment: Create a unique file name for each job using e.g. `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`. Then only return `Result.success()` from `doWork()` after the file has been uploaded AND deleted. Then you don’t need to check if any file remains to upload during app start, because of WorkManager guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

I saved the image onto the filesystem and then passed the file path in my Data object. Inside my worker class, I uploaded the image by retrieving the image using the file path that I passed when I was creating my data object