# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data cannot occupy more than 10240 bytes when serialized

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I want to process image using WorkManager. I am getting error while sending byte array to the work manager.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data cannot occupy more than 10240 bytes when serialized

Below is my code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] ImgData = stream.toByteArray();
Data data = new Data.Builder()
            .putByteArray("ByteArrayData",ImgData)
            .build();
```

Please help or suggest any alternatives.

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456344/uploading-large-bitmaps-using-workmanager

Comment: I have asked for the alternative. I am capturing bitmap from textureview, converting it to byte array and passing it to work manager for background processing. I don't want to block UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its all local android development, cant you just use the file path and pass it like that to the worker?

Processing the whole image in the worker will cause this error - looks like the data limit is 10kb, check the docs here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

So you should refer the image somehow and not pass the image itself.

Comment: Yes, I can save byte array as jpg file in local storage. I will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: But in that case, I've to save byte array to jpg file and again convert jpg to byte array inside WorkManager.....

Comment: What do you want to do with the image? Can you explain the whole thing? There is an example in the docs of a filter being applied to some images, and later uploaded to a server, perhaps it can provide some insight?

Comment: So we cannot use CoroutineWorker with WorkManager to scale bitmaps??

Comment: We can, but you must refer the image by it´s path and not pass the image as a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send data with size more than 10240 bytes. You have to save that data somewhere with some id so that you can access it using that id and pass that id to the worker. For eg, you can save your image url or uri in the database with some id as the primary key(you can use auto-generated id), pass that id to the worker and in worker use that id to get image from database and do whatever you want to do.